# Can not display Image from firebase firestore and react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that gets the database from firestore, and the images being held on firestorage, my application works perfectly fine however the image shows as undefined, after lots of different trials I noticed that the Image loads ,and then something clears it out, not sure what I am missing on my code.

### Code retrieving data from Firestore and Firestorage

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getList = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(query(edu_Collection, orderBy('date', 'desc')))
      setEducationList(
        data.docs.map(doc  =>
        {
          let data = {
            id: doc.id, 
            name: doc.data().name, 
            location: doc.data().location, 
            image: doc.data().image, 
            date: doc.data().date.toDate()
          } as Education;
          
          const reference = ref(storage, data.image)
          getDownloadURL(reference)
          .then(url => { data.fullPath = url; setLoaded(true); console.log(url) })
          .catch(err => console.error(err))

          
          return data
        })
      )
    }
    getList()

  }, [])
```

### Rendering part

```
    <Row>
      {educationList.map((item: Education) => (
        <Col key={item.id} xs={4}>
          <Card>
          <div className={styles.CardImageContainer}>
            <Card.Img 
              className={styles.CardImage} 
              variant="top" 
              src={item.fullPath} />
          </div>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              {item.location}
            </Card.Text>
            <CustomDate date={item.date} />
          </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem maybe because of the way you mixed up promise and async await. Please try my solution

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getList = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(query(edu_Collection, orderBy('date', 'desc')));
      const educations = [];

      for (let index = 0; index < data.docs.length; index++) {
        const doc = data.docs[index];
        let data = {
          id: doc.id, 
          name: doc.data().name, 
          location: doc.data().location, 
          image: doc.data().image, 
          date: doc.data().date.toDate()
        } as Education;

        const reference = ref(storage, data.image);
        data.fullPath =await getDownloadURL(reference);

        educations.push(data);
      }

      setEducationList(educations);
    };

    getList()
  }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks @TramLoc for your response, unfortunately I still face the same issue after applying your code, not sure what I am missing there, please advise

Comment: did you check whether the data.image is correct? if this path is wrong, you won't be able to get the downloadUrl

Comment: Open your storage console and copy a correct path and do hard coding into your current code to see if it works

Comment: for example: const reference = ref(storage, "folder1/image1.png");

Comment: yes, when I replace the url coming from the firestore with static one, it works fine. also when I do console.log for the url after retrieving it, it shows correctly on the log.